# IIS 8.5 Ignoring revoked certificates in CRL and serving pages to certificates that are revoked

Tags: x509, iis-8, self-signed, certificate-revocation

I am currently struggling with an issue which I am now led to believe is being caused by IIS.

I am currently testing a self signed PKI setup with a Root CA (MyNewCA), two signed Client Certificates (certificate1, certificate2) and a Revocation list (revocationlist.crl) that is also signed by the CA.

I have added certificate1 to the revocation list and published it to a http port 80 site that exists on our network. I have then created a fake site (testsite) that is secured via a TLS certificate.

From a client machine, I have run the CertUtil commands on both certificate1 and certificate2 and these commands correctly access the http crl site, and recognise that certificate1 is revoked, and certificate2 is a legitimate non revoked certificate.

However, when I connect to the testsite via a client browser, and supply the invalid certificate - IIS still serves me the page instead of giving me a 403.13 error.

I have done a ton of reading, and it seems that at times there are CRL caching issues, however the first revocation list that I published had certificate1's serial number in it, and hence even a cached version will contain that revoked cert.

I have changed the CertCheckMode in RegEdit on the IIS server to the value 4 in an attempt to force IIS to fetch the latest crl on EVERY request, but even that setting is still allowing the revoked certificate to be served to the client.

The CRL itself has;
Effective date of 19th January 2016
Next update of 20th January 2017

I can provide the certutil output if it is useful, or any other log data that would help in pinpointing the problem.

I ran Fiddler on my client machine and verified that the crl was fetched from the Http site.

If anyone can provide any insight into this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior. IIS do not prevent access to SSL sites even if there are revocation issues with the SSL cert. It is up to client what to do with the information it receives from the server. It is up to client to perform (or to not perform) revocation checking and to make decision about further steps.

In addition, make sure if client's cache has the most recent CRL.

Comment: If this is true then it would seem that the entire point of a CRL is redundant? I have revoked certificate1 and it's serial number exists in the revocation list. When I load a client browser and select certificate1 as my client certificate, I presumed that IIS would take that client certificate, check the serial number against it's CRL, and then serve up a 403.13 error due to the fact that the client certificate trying to authenticate has been revoked? What is the purpose of the CRL if not to check the client certificate and restrict access to those certificates that are invalid?

Comment: Are you referring to client certificates or server certificates? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: client certificates - I have revoked certificate1 (client) but IIS still serves me up the requested page without a 403 error. I have run certutil -urlfetch -certificate1.cer and it lists the fact that the certificate is revoked. I can download the crl direct using certutil -URL http://mycrlsite/RootRevocation.crl. Caching shouldnt be playing an issue here either as the current crl had certificate1's serial number revoked in the first copy I published.

Comment: please, meake sure if you ran certutil command on IIS server. In addition, make sure revocation settings on IIS are in secure state: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/10/15/disable-client-certificate-revocation-check-on-iis.aspx (the article talks about disabling, so you need opposite).

Comment: I can confirm that running cert util on the iis server itself produces the same result and if I load a browser on the IIS machine I can also manually download the CRL via the browser. All the revocation settings are set correctly also and I have tried clearing the cache using both "certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now" and "certutil -urlcache crl delete". I have restarted the IIS machine also to try to force the CRL to be picked up on the box but it is still allowing the revoked client to access the test site. Thanyou for your help on this - it's appreciated!

Comment: Ok, next option would be to examine CAPI2 eventlog. When client connects with client certificate, there should be a bunch of record associated with that certificate. CAPI2 logging can give much more details about the issue.

Comment: I was not aware of the CAPI2 logs - they are a great help and very detailed - thankyou. After coming back to work after a couple of days break, it seems that the revocation has now taken effect and I get one revoked client request and one that is allowed access to the page. This leads me to believe that it must be caching - I have tried setting the CertCheckMode value to always fetch a fresh crl for testing but this doesn't seem to affect the outcome. I will continue investigating - thanks again